# Google GCP VM instances can not access(ping) each other?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

--Case A--

1.Create one vpc network(net-10-232-0-0) with two subnetworks(10.232.20.0/24 and 10.232.30.0/24)

2.Create two VM instances with internal IPs(10.232.20.21 and 10.232.30.31)

3.Create ingress/engress firewall rules

both vm instances can access(ping) each other.

.

--Case B--

1.Create two vpc network(net-10-232-20-0 and net-10-232-30-0) with two subnetworks(10.232.20.0/24 and 10.232.30.0/24)

2.Create two VM instances with internal IPs(10.232.20.21 and 10.232.30.31)

3.Create ingress/engress firewall rules

both vm instances can not access(ping) each other.

.

is there something missed?!

Answer (score 0):

No, this is an expected behavior.

Two VPCs are different networks and isolates their resources, that's the point of a VPC.

If you need to connect resources from different VPCs, you may need a [VPC peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering).

In addition, your question is well explained in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#specifications).